# Root directory -- verifying ownership -- did I put the file in the right place?

Tags: root

My site is built in PHP.

I need to upload a file to the root directory, to verify ownership of the domain.

I put the file in the first window I see when I log in over ftp, but the file doesn't show up at the relevant url.

Where do I place a file so that it's in the root directory?

Comment: Belongs to webmaster, not SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root is the `DocumentRoot` of your site.

It is basically the public folder of your website.

The folder where your index.php is (or the first file that is called).

Comment: there's a folder called 'production' (there's a staging system) -- in 'production', there's a file 'index.php', but if I put this verification file in there, it doesn't show up at the relevant url still

Comment: @Richard: If you are 100% sure that's the root of the website it may have something to do with some rewriterule if you use it. For what service do you need to verify, since there may be other verification options for you.